# PHP - Executing Python from PHP

Tags: php, python, html

I'm attempting to run a Python script on server from a webpage, I decided to go with PHP in order to execute it. From what I read from tutorials on line, it should be simple enough just to work, however whenever I try to submit my form with PHP, I get the following error code.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/dertyui/public_html/root/wwwdustin/rss/sm/runpython.php on line 6
```

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, the code is so short I expected it just to work. I made sure to double check that safe mode was off on my server, and have the file permissions set to 755. Here's my other code:

Submit Form Page (index.html)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="runpython.php" method="post">
Status: <input type="text" name="status" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body
</html>
```

RunPython.php (To run Python script)

```
<?php

$commandtorun = '/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/dertyui/python/scripts/socialmedia/StatusPoster.py --accountname dustin --statusupdate ' . $_POST["status"] . '--statusupdatelink http://google.ca'

exec($commandtorun);

?>
```

Comment: the parse error is pretty descriptive

Comment: Besides @Lusitanian's answer, you might want to put a space before --statusupdatelink

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a semicolon after your first line which declares the variable.